# Access assets folder from global.scss

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

To access the assets folder from within any file in the `scr/app` directory, I simply call `../assets/` and it works fine.

However, when I'm in the `global.scss` file, I can't. It gives me a "Resource not found" error. I've tried other variations to call the directory (`../../assets/`, `./assets`, etc.), but it just keeps failing.

I'm working with Ionic 6

Answer (score 0):

I had to access it from root directory and worked:

```
...
src: url(/assets/...)
...
```

I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do, but this works on all files of the application when I access it this way.